# How to make cocos2d v1.0.1 support Retina?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I have to work with a project made by another developer. This project uses cocos2d v1.0.1. And the problem is it doesn't support Retina display. When i go into `[director enableRetinaDisplay:YES];` method i see that it returns NO on the line:

```
if (! [openGLView_ respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentScaleFactor:)])
    return NO;
```

So the question is - is it possible somehow to make this version of cocos2d support Retina?

EDIT: I'm running it in iOS 6.1 simulator. Retina simulator.

Comment: hmmm.... it has been a while but i'm pretty certain it does. When you get that NO, what are you running on ?  is the simulator hardware properly set ?

Comment: simulator ios 6.1. it is Retina

Comment: and also real iPhone device iOS 6. Retina. still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` is negation operator. `!condition` evaluates to true if and only if `condition` is false.

`return NO;` line will only be executed if `openGLView_` does *not* respond to `setContentScaleFactor:`.

UIView's `contentScaleFactor` property is available in iOS 4.0 and later. Checking for availability of the setter of this property is a way to check if device itself is capable of retina. If `openGLView_` does *not* respond to `setContentScaleFactor:`, then this device doesn't have retina, and this is why CCDirector's `enableRetinaDisplay` returns NO.

If you are running your code on device and getting NO here, then this device doesn't have retina. If you are running it on simulator, make sure that it's simulating at least iOS 4.0. To get retina device simulator, select any of retina configurations in Hardware->Device menu.

**Edit**: 
Is `openGLView_` nil? In Objective C you can call any method on nil, and it will do nothing and return nil (zero, NULL, NO). You have to create an EAGLView and set it as CCDirector's OpenGL view *before* enabling retina display.

Comment: i'm runnning it in simulator iOS 6.1 Retina

Comment: and just tried it on Retina iPhone ios 6. still doesn't respond to this selector